# Strange issue with python when collecting data from xenserver

Tags: python, python-2.7, sockets, xen, strace

I am having a weird issue whereby I am using the following python script and when I run it on one host it works fine, on another machine it gets stuck at around 65 values, i.e. after this it freezes. I also included the strace. Both machines are Centos, same network.

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import XenAPI
import string, time, os, ConfigParser, sys, re
def errorAndExit(message):
  print "ERROR: Something went wrong! -", message
  exit(1)

def grabXenData(session, config):

  try:
    vms = session.xenapi.VM.get_all()
  except:
    errorAndExit("Couldn't retrieve all VM's")
  for vm in vms:
    record = session.xenapi.VM.get_record(vm)
    if (record["power_state"] == "Running") and not (record["is_control_domain"]):
        if (record["actions_after_crash"] != "destroy"):
            print record["name_label"]


if __name__ == '__main__':

  CONFIG_FILE = (os.getcwd() + "/config.txt")
  config = ConfigParser.ConfigParser()
  config.read([CONFIG_FILE])

  wait = config.get('XENAPI', 'WAIT')

  # time.sleep expects a float, convert the var here.
  wait = float(wait)

  url = "http://" + config.get('XENAPI', 'HOSTNAME')
  print url
  username =  config.get('XENAPI', 'USERNAME')
  password =  config.get('XENAPI', 'PASSWORD')
  while True:
    session = XenAPI.Session(url)
    print session
    try:
      session.xenapi.login_with_password(username, password)
    except:
      errorAndExit("Could not connect to host, CHECK: URL, username, password")

    grabXenData(session, config)
    session.xenapi.session.logout()
    exit()
```

Here is the stack trace:

```
open("/usr/lib64/python2.7/httplib.py", O_RDONLY) = 4
fstat(4, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=48234, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7fa108b7e000
read(4, "r\"\"\"HTTP/1.1 client library\n\n<in"..., 4096) = 4096
read(4, "THENTICATION_REQUIRED = 407\nREQU"..., 4096) = 4096
read(4, "nread'):\n            unread = se"..., 4096) = 4096
write(2, "    ", 4)                     = 4
write(2, "line = self.fp.readline(_MAXLINE"..., 38) = 38
close(4)                                = 0
munmap(0x7fa108b7e000, 4096)            = 0
write(2, "  File \"/usr/lib64/python2.7/soc"..., 63) = 63
open("/usr/lib64/python2.7/socket.py", O_RDONLY) = 4
fstat(4, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=20512, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7fa108b7e000
read(4, "# Wrapper module for _socket, pr"..., 4096) = 4096
read(4, "oo long.\"\n    errorTab[10064] = "..., 4096) = 4096
read(4, "sed\" is a property, see below\n  "..., 4096) = 4096
read(4, "        try:\n                   "..., 4096) = 4096
read(4, "            nl = data.find('\\n')"..., 4096) = 4096
write(2, "    ", 4)                     = 4
write(2, "data = self._sock.recv(self._rbu"..., 39) = 39
close(4)                                = 0
munmap(0x7fa108b7e000, 4096)            = 0
write(2, "KeyboardInterrupt", 17)       = 17
write(2, "\n", 1)                       = 1
rt_sigaction(SIGINT, {SIG_DFL, [], SA_RESTORER, 0x7fa10838d130}, {0x7fa1086ab6a0, [], SA_RESTORER, 0x7fa10838d130}, 8) = 0
close(3)                                = 0
close(8)                                = 0
exit_group(1)                           = ?
+++ exited with 1 +++
```

Thanks in advance. Any more info please let us know.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why but you should use sys.exit, also except Exception.

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import XenAPI
import string, time, os, ConfigParser, sys, re
def errorAndExit(message):
  print "ERROR: Something went wrong! -", message
  sys.exit(1)

def grabXenData(session, config):
  vms = []
  try:
    vms = session.xenapi.VM.get_all()
  except Exception:
    errorAndExit("Couldn't retrieve all VM's")
  for vm in vms:
    record = session.xenapi.VM.get_record(vm)
    if (record["power_state"] == "Running") and not (record["is_control_domain"]):
        if (record["actions_after_crash"] != "destroy"):
            print record["name_label"]


if __name__ == '__main__':

  CONFIG_FILE = (os.getcwd() + "/config.txt")
  config = ConfigParser.ConfigParser()
  config.read([CONFIG_FILE])

  wait = config.get('XENAPI', 'WAIT')

  # time.sleep expects a float, convert the var here.
  wait = float(wait)

  url = "http://" + config.get('XENAPI', 'HOSTNAME')
  print url
  username =  config.get('XENAPI', 'USERNAME')
  password =  config.get('XENAPI', 'PASSWORD')
  while True:
    session = XenAPI.Session(url)
    print session
    try:
      session.xenapi.login_with_password(username, password)
    except Exception:
      errorAndExit("Could not connect to host, CHECK: URL, username, password")

    grabXenData(session, config)
    session.xenapi.session.logout()
    sys.exit(0)
```

You got an error `ATHENTICATION_REQUIRED`:

```
open("/usr/lib64/python2.7/httplib.py", O_RDONLY) = 4
fstat(4, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=48234, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7fa108b7e000
read(4, "r\"\"\"HTTP/1.1 client library\n\n<in"..., 4096) = 4096
read(4, "THENTICATION_REQUIRED = 407\nREQU"..., 4096) = 4096
```

I think you should try if you are using python bindings "right".